# Object is NULL immediately after Registering valid json using Defaultbuilder

Tags: c#, json

I have a json object as

```
{
  "Command": [
    {
      "start": {
        "name": "Get Connected",
        "duration": 208
      }
    },
    {
      "stop": {
        "name": "Get Connected",
        "duration": 208
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

When I register using the following and then testing the commandList is NULL

```
services.Configure<CommandList>(configuration.GetSection("Command"));
var commandList = configuration.GetSection("Command").Get<CommandList>();
```

The class looks like

```
public class CommandList
{
    [JsonPropertyName("command")]
    public List<Command> Command { get; set; }
}

public class Command
{
    [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]
    [JsonPropertyName("start")]
    public Attributes Start { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]
    [JsonPropertyName("stop")]
    public Attributes Stop { get; set; }
}

public class Attributes
{
    [JsonPropertyName("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("duration")]
    public long Duration { get; set; }
}
```

I ultimately want to inject this into an object as follows

```
public CommandService(ILogger<CommandService> logger,
            IOptions<CommandList> options)
```

Until my test returns data and not null this isn't possible. I would appreciate help to explain what I am doing wrong. Other Json structures work OK for me, so is the Json object above valid for what I want to do?

Answer (score 0):

if you check GetSection("Command") you will see that you have just an array, so use this code to get data

```
List<Command> commandList = configuration.GetSection("Command")
                                         .Get<List<Command>>();
```

to add to configuration

```
services.Configure<List<Command>>(configuration.GetSection("Command"));
services.AddScoped<CommandService>();

public class CommandService
{
    private readonly List<Command> _commandSettings;

    public CommandService(IOptions<List<Command>> commandPolicy)
    {
        _commandSettings = commandPolicy.Value;
    }
    public List<Command> GetSettings() => _commandSettings;
}
```

to use

```
var _serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider(true);
IServiceScope scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();

List<Command> settings = scope.ServiceProvider
                              .GetService<CommandService>().GetSettings();
```

or you can inject it to a constructor of the class you need to use it

```
public class MyClass
{
....
public MyClsss(CommandService _service) 
{
....
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this enables ,me to see the data immediately after the registration. Can this be injected as IOptions or directly as the commandList?